# Split dataframe into Excel files by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```
>>> df
    id    name    score    subject
    0001   'bob'    100    'math'
    0001   'bob'     67    'science'
    0001   'bob'     63    'bio'
    0002  'jack'     67    'math'
    0002  'jack'     98    'science' 
    0002  'jack'     90    'bio'
    0003  'jack'     60    'math'
    0003  'jack'     78    'science' 
    0003  'rose'     87    'bio'
```

I want to filter every `id`'s data into a new DataFrame and write to an Excel file based on its id. So, the above `df` will be filtered into 3 DataFrames whose `ids` are `0001`, `0002` and `0003`, and all the DataFrames will be written to individual excel files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, get a list of the unique ID values

```
uniquevalues = np.unique(df[['id']].values)
```

Then iterate on it and export each dataframe with those IDs in a CSV file

```
for id in uniquevalues:
    newdf = df[df['id'] == id]
    newdf.to_csv("dataframe "+id+".csv", sep='\t')
```

If you have only those three IDs, then you can just pass the `for` and do the same thing manually like

```
newdf = df[df['id'] == "0001"]
newdf.to_csv("dataframe0001.csv", sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 8):

IIUC, on your example you can just filter the dataframe by `id` with:

```
df1 = df[df['id'] == 0001]
```

and the same for other `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to convert df row to (str) first, otherwise kept getting dtype errors.

```
df['sample']=df['sample'].apply(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

First we have the data

```
data= { 
     "id":
     ['0001','0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002', '0003', '0003', '0003'],
     "name":
     ['bob','bob','bob','jack','jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack',  'rose'],
     "score":
     [100,67,63,67,98,90,60,78,87],
     "subject":
     ['math','science','bio','math','science' ,'bio','math','science' ,'bio' ]
}
```

Then we process it

```
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
ids = table['id'].unique() # we get an array of unique ids
for i in ids:
    # You can refer to variables in the environment
    # by prefixing them with an '@' character
    idtable = table.query(" id == @i ") # we filter the dataframe by id
    title = f"table_id_{i}.csv" # we set a unique name for the csv file
    idtable.to_csv(title) # we save the filtered dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' groupby splits a dataframe according to a grouper. So simply groupby id and write each split df to an excel file.

```py
for Id, d in df.groupby('id'):
    d.to_excel(f'Id_{Id}.xlsx')
```

This creates 3 excel files named "Id_1.xlsx", "Id_2.xlsx" and "Id_3.xlsx".

Similarly, one can create a dictionary of dfs (where the keys are ids)

```py
dict([*df.groupby('id')])
```

or a list of dfs

```py
[d for _, d in df.groupby('id')]
```

With OP's data, it looks like

[image]